# How can I easily create a Func<T> from a method name?

Tags: c#, wcf, delegates, anonymous-delegates

Trying to reduce code duplication in a project which wraps a modern Wcf interface around an old Dll which used to power an Asmx web service.

I'm trying to write a generic helper method which takes 4 types (Old and New versions of the Input and Output types), the input document and a Func pointing at the method in the old dll.

```
private static WcfOutType WrapCallAroundOldBl<WcfOutType, WcfInType, LinqOutType, LinqInType>(WcfInType input, Func<LinqInType, LinqOutType> method)
```

Thought I could do something like this:

```
        var output = WrapCallAroundOldBl<
            WcfOutputTypeName, 
            WcfINputTypeName, 
            LinqToXsdOutputTypeName,
            LinqToXsdInputTypeName>(input, Our.Old.Dll.Methods.MethodName);
        return output;
```

But I get:

```
cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Func<OutputTypeName, InputTypeName>'
```

This works:

```
        var output = WrapCallAroundOldBl<
            WcfOutputTypeName, 
            WcfINputTypeName, 
            LinqToXsdOutputTypeName,
            LinqToXsdInputTypeName>(input, i => Our.Old.Dll.Methods.MethodName(i));
        return output;
```

But I was wondering is there is anyway to turn these "method groups" directly into the Func.
Just extract the delegate somehow.

Comment: Whats the signature of `Our.Old.Dll.Methods.MethodName`?

Comment: Remember that `MethodName` may have multiple overrides which is why you get a `method group` (though it may only contain a single method)

Comment: All of the public methods in the Old Dll are `LinqOutType MethodName(LinqInType)`

Comment: Ah, so I have to put in the `i => Method(i)` as this selects one overload from a group of methods?

Comment: No, you should not need to wrap the method call in a lambda/anonymous method. But without a good code example, where we can see all of the relevant method signatures and types, no one can tell you exactly why the conversion fails. Have you tried simply casting? I.e. `(Func<LinqInType, LinqOutType>)Our.Old.Dll.Methods.MethodName`? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve